# Windows Server 2003 DNS cached lookups modification

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

Is it possible to modify the entries in the cached lookup?
I need to temporarily change the resolution of an IP address of a domain name to something else. I can't wait until DNS updates.

Sorry, forgot to mention that the interface of the server has DNS set to itself.
DNS server is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an authoritative zone in your Windows 2003 DNS with the copy of the updated zone.

This is a common practice (for instance) to rewrite the company's web IP address or to block a site.

Comment: i thought that you're not supposed to make an authoritive zone for domains that you do not own/manage.

Comment: In your own network you do whatever you want! :)

Comment: I would do it absolutely the same way.

Comment: Good! Nice to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the hosts file (under c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) to put an IP and hostname combination which will override the DNS resolver.  Just remember to remove the entry when you're done to avoid any confusion in the future.

Comment: I've done that... but it still resolves the address to the other IP

Comment: Did you flush the local DNS cache?  ipconfig -flushdns

Comment: Yes, I have flushed the DNS cache. Still resolving the old IP

Comment: The .../etc/hosts file is used by local (e.g. the machine in with the file is) resolver. The DNS server does not read the .../etc/hosts file when does name resolutions for clients

Comment: It works only for server itself, not for clients.

Comment: Right, I was assuming he would do this on the client system he was using to perform the lookup, not on the server.